# Server Not operational

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, advertisement-server

This is the connectionString am using in my web.config:

```
<add key="GlobalAppStoreActiveDirectoryPath" value="GC://10.xxx.xx.xxx/DC=company,DC=com"/>
```

the code in my authentication page:

```
using (var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domUserName, password))
{
try
{
using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot))
{
    searcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
    var result = searcher.FindOne();//---> am getting an exception here "server not operational"
```

The `telnet` to the Active Directory Server is working 
`telnet 10.xxx.xx.xxx 3268`

But am not getting authenticated.Plz help in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try the following as your LDAP connexion string (it works for me) :

```
"LDAP://10.xxx.xx.xxx:3268/DC=company,DC=com"
```